# Take the last 2 bits of a nibble in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have this byte: `10111011` and i want to split into 2 nibble (msb and lsb).
After that i want to take the last 2 bits from the lsb (so i want `11` from `1011`).
I know that:
With `10011011 >> 4` i get the msb (1001) 
With `10011011 & 0xf` i get the lsb (1011)

Now what can i do to take the `11` from lsb `1011`?

Comment: "Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just the same: `bits = lsb & 0x03`

Answer (score 0):

The bitmask for the first two bits is 3, so simply use:

```
int val = x & 3;
```

Since the bits are already in the proper position you don't need some shift operator.

For the above value it would be.

```
val = (x >> 4) & 3;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd do:

```
foo & 0x03
```

Where `foo` is the bit-pattern you want masked.